# Andriod Genymotion Error Appears on APK Execution

Tags: android, genymotion

Error message appears when executing apk in mobile android on Genymotion desktop. Genyomotion version: 3.0.3, license: personal use.

> An error occurred while deploying the file, please refer to Genymotion
>   logs for more information.

Note: I tried to use more than one android version, but error still appears.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your genymotion logs, located:

Windows:
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed\<virtual device name>\Logs`

macOS:
`$HOME/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/<virtual device name>/`

Linux:
`$HOME/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/<virtual device name>/`

according to docs:
https://docs.genymotion.com/desktop/3.0/03_Virtual_devices/035_Generating_virtual_device_logs.html

Comment: i can not arrive any thing after open gynemotion logs ?!!

Comment: What does that mean ? Are the logs empty ? Are there not any logs ?

Comment: thanks all, i solved this problem, The problem was due to issue in apk files.